# best way to do this im using resource and eloquent laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Any best way to do this will be gratefull

what this do is grab the input from a form and save it to the database.

```
public function update()
{

    $file = Input::file('path');

$destinationPath = 'img/';
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
// $extension =$file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
$upload_success = Input::file('path')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
 $photo = Photo::find($_POST['id']);
    $photo->caption = $_POST['caption'];
    $photo->path = $destinationPath . $filename;
    $photo->save();


if( $upload_success ) {
return Redirect::to('photos/'.$_POST['id'].'/edit')->withInput()->with('success', 'Photo       have been updated.');
} else {
 return Response::json('error', 400);
 }
}
```

this work just fine but i wonder if there a simplify way to do this like how i can get post data from the form send to update to update the photo information instead of me using the $_POST and get the id from the form parse into the update($id)  ect. Thanks

Comment: Would you edit into the body of your question, prior to your code, what this actually does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Input class, instead of accessing the post directly.

I would probably re-write the function a little like this:

```
public function update()
{
    $file = Input::file('path');
    $destinationPath = 'img/';
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    if( Input::file('path')->move($destinationPath, $filename) )
    {
       $photo = Photo::find(Input::get('id'));
       $photo->caption = Input::get('caption');
       $photo->path = $destinationPath . $filename;
       $photo->save();
       return Redirect::to('photos/'.$_POST['id'].'/edit')->withInput()->with('success', 'Photo       have been updated.');
    } 
    else 
    {
       return Response::json('error', 400);
    }
}
```

The other option is to extract some of this data directly into your Photo model, and do it in there.

Comment: thank you bud im still on heavy learning and i like laraval even more :D